# Angularjs/Javascript Do not reload page, but change url and update screen

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Recently I have come into a problem where I need to update the page using angular, update the url, but not reload the page.  Confused?  Let me further explain.  I have a table of data (uses ng-grid) and I want it so when I click row 1 angular prints out a one and changes the url to 'currentUrl/1' without reloading the page.  Then I click row 4, a 4 prints out and changes the url to 'currentUrl/4'.  Is this possible with angular to do this.  To make my page not reload every time I clicked a row, I put the following

```
var lastRoute = $route.current;
    $scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(event) {
        $route.current = lastRoute;
    });
```

Which it does everything I want, changes url, page doesn't reload, but now angular is not updating that number.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check this: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: Thanks, but the fix I am looking for has to be stable, and in the documentation, it says that it is not.

Answer (score 0):

It would help to see the part of the code that prints out the number, but your code for changing the URL without refreshing the route looks fine.

Without more information, a shot in the dark is that your controller is updating a `$scope` variable but this update isn't getting applied by Angular.

Try wrapping the variable update like so:

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
  $scope.numberToPrint = newNumber;
});
```

The basic idea behind calling `$scope.$apply` is that you have to manually coax Angular into updating any bindings listening to the variable. Although this should normally be taken care of, what is possibly happening is that by preventing a route change from occurring you are not actually having Angular digest the new variable.

[Here is an article which can explain `$apply` better.](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html)

Comment: Because I don't really have a full understanding of what is going on I cannot provide working sample code.  But, the $scope.$apply did not work because of a '$digest already in progress' error.  And I think when ever I run my app with the locationChangeSuccess it does not run my $watch function(next comment), but when I comment the location thing out of my program, it runs through the $watch function(have console.log in there).  Is that enouph information for what it could be?

Comment: $scope.$watch(function() { return selectedPartFactory.part.id }, function(n) {
            $http.get(afHttp.baseUrl + "/" + $scope.grid.name + "/" + n)
                .success(function(data) {
                    //$log.log($scope.grid.name);
                    $scope.grid.data = data;
                })
            ;
        });